# Shuffling array of ints with chunks of ints

Tags: java, arrays, shuffle

I am trying to shuffle an array of ints with chunks and I'm having very little success so far.

I have an array of 18 ints from 0 to 17

```
array = new int[18];
for(int i = 0; i < 18; i++){
    array[i] = i; 
}
```

And an array for each chunk of ints that I want to shuffle

```
int[] chunks = {2, 3, 10, 3};
```

The array of ints starts like 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17
When the first element of the chunk array of 2 gets chosen, the first 2 elements of the array, 0 and 1 are chosen. 1 is moved to the end of the array and 0 follows.

Now the order is 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,0,1

For the 2nd element of the chunks array, it has a value of 3, so 2,3,4 are chosen and are put on top of the 0 and 1.

Now the order is 5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,2,3,4,0,1

This continues until the array of ints are fully shuffled with all of the chunks

The array fully shuffled with the chunks is 15,16,17,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,2,3,4,0,1

## Research

The ways I have tried programming this so far have been with

```
    for(int i = 0; i < chunks[0] i++) {
    int first = array[0];
    System.arraycopy(array, 1, array, 0, array.length-1);
    array[array.length - 1] = first;
}
```

## Update

This is the code I am working with now and I am getting the following result
10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, instead of
15,16,17,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,2,3,4,0,1

```
    int[] array2 = array.clone();
    int temp = array2[0];
    int chunkIndex = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int chunkCount = 0;

    //Loops 4 times
    for(int i = 0; i < chunks.length; i++) {  
        //Loops as many times for the chunk element
        while(chunks[i] > count) {
            for(int k = 1; k < array2.length; k++) {  
                //Move all the elements back
                 array2[k-1] = array2[k];
            }

            chunkIndex = array2.length-1 - chunkCount;
            array2[chunkIndex] = temp;

            temp = array2[0];

            count++;
         }

         //Increment the limit
         chunkCount += chunks[i]; 
         //System.out.println(chunkCount);

      }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated and also if you need me to clarify anything let me know.

Thanks

Comment: it may be helpful if you can share us the code you have tried so far?

Comment: even by the syntax error in your `for` loop this won't compile due to your last line where you want to assign an `Array` to an `int` (`array[...]` is an `int`)

Comment: Yes you are right, that was a mistype on my part. I mean to put in first rather than array

Comment: You should not use `arraycopy` but simply an index to remember where is the "end" of the original array, the position of the last element. Then this is just a shift of element.

Comment: I confirm, way simpler using an `endIndex` to know where to insert the values. The algorithm is quite simple, then to write the code, this only need a three loops (might be a simpler way) an a few minutes.

Comment: The simplest approach will be to create a target array and copy the values over 'in chunks'.

Comment: Yes, it seems there are quite a few approaches to solving this problem but I ended up going with AxelH suggestion in the end. However, thank you for your suggestion Dan Allen and I may use it when I refactor my code later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will not give you the code, since this is a good exercice.

But first, don't copy the array again, and again.

A basic solution would be to :

```
1 - Read the chunk length
2 - Save the first value in a temp variable
3 - Shift every value on the left
4 - Put the temp variable at the end
```

This is a simple way to shift a value in an array.

Now, for every chunk, you need to put the values before the last one, so you just need to remember where is the `index` of this chunk. This is just the `lastIndex` - `chunk length`. This will be the limit for the shifting and where to put the temp value.

With this, you can easily write a solution that would work in the best condition.

*Of couse there is some problem if the chunks read to many values (if you want 13 item in a array of 12 cells.*

EDIT :

1 - You should save the `temp` before shifting the array, you override the value first then try to get it.

2 - You are always shifting the full array, so you are going to move the first chunk after you have move it. This is were you need a `index` that will decrement

```
int endIndex = array2.length; //###  2  ###
while(chunks[i] > count) {
    temp = array2[0]; //###  1  ###

    for(int k = 1; k < endIndex; k++) { //###  2  ###
        //Move all the elements back
        array2[k-1] = array2[k];
    }

    ...
}
endIndex -= chunks[i];
```

It should be a bit better, I don't have the time to test this unfortunalty.

Comment: I have a much better understanding of how to solve this problem thanks to you. I have almost completed it but I keep overriding elements in the array at the end.

Comment: @Aaron, check this few updates, it should be better. You are not far from my solution I think. But this still need some improvment.

Comment: that update really helped me. My program is now shuffling through the ints as expected. Thanks for helping me solve it!

Comment: My shuffle method is working (code is in my answer) but I am looking to reduce the algorithm complexity from O(n3) to O(n). Do you have any hints on how to do this?

Comment: @Aaron First, use the _edit_ option below your question to update it, don't use Answer to ask more. Since this is working but you won't a review of it, you should ask a question on [codereview.se], this is where you ask for improvment on working code. Stackoverflow is more about error

Comment: Ah right that makes sense. I'll post there and see how it goes. Thanks once again for your help!